# Is this Patent Still Valid? (Hat / Cap)

Tags: ep0639338b1

I'm new to Patents, and wanted to know if this EU issued patent is still valid..

https://www.google.com/patents/EP0639338B1?cl=en
https://register.epo.org/application?number=EP94303053

It says it is granted years ago, and I have no idea what this means: "Lapsed in a contracting state announced via postgrant inform. from nat. office to epo"

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. The filling date of the patent was 27.04.1994, plus 20 years = it expired on April 2014.

The status "lapsed in a contracting state" is something unique with the EPO system, which creates a bundle of patents for several contracting states (this is a choice made by the applicant).

Sometimes you may see a granted patent appearing to have lapsed in several contracting states, but not all. This may happen right after grant, wherein the patent proprietor deliberately does not provide translation and/or other requirements set by the national patent offices, effecting that way a "withdrawal" from those states (its cheaper and faster).
Sometimes, the patent proprietor decides after a few years that he does not care e.g. for Austria and he simply stops renewing the fees in this country. The EP registry usually is up to date, but don't count on that to make important decisions: after grant always check national patent offices, regarding EP patents.
Last but not least, if the patent lapses because it completed its 20-year-term, you will still see "lapsed in a contracting state", because this is the correct legal term. The EPO awards patents, but the rights acquired relate to national laws.